# Meta query with string NOT ending like pattern

Tags: meta-query, regex

I need to find all posts that do NOT have in a specific meta key values ending with "*.mp3*". I know that I can use `REGEXP` for this, but I can't figure out how to do it. My code now returns all the posts whose meta value ENDS with "*.mp3*". Any help?

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'audio/mpeg', 
    'numberposts'    => -1, 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_wp_attached_file', 
            'value'   => '.mp3$', 
            'compare' => 'REGEXP', 
        ) ), 
);

$audiofiles = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: note that by using `get_posts` it will apply several additional parameters that aren't good for performance that `WP_Query` wouldn't normally do when used on its own. You should add `'suppress_filters' => false` so that caching plugins, object cache, and plugins can use their filters properly. You'll also need to adjust your regex so that it matches everything that doesn't end in `.mp3` rather than the inverse, but that part is a generic regex question rather than a WordPress specific question

Comment: As an aside, what are you trying to do that requires this? What's the problem this solves? There's a _very_ high chance that you can solve it with a different method. Also use `posts_per_page` instead of `numberposts`, and set the value to a high value you never expect to hit but know that your server can handle safely, not `-1`

Comment: @TomJNowell You are right, Tom! I will go a little different way, using your suggestions. Thanks a lot! P.S. I close this question.

Comment: this could still be an interesting question/answer, consider undeleting it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex that doesn't match path that is ending with .mp3, you can use this

```regex
.*\.(?!mp3)
```